# Ubuntu 12.4 HDD files can't be seen by XP on an external USB drive

Tags: usb, hard-drive, windows-xp

Due to a power supply malfunction I rescued the hard drive and placed it into an external USB storage box and plugged it into an XP professional O/S computer to recover emails, music etc but XP cant see the files but does see the drive.

The system was working 100% and I am certain the files are there but XP cannot see any of Linux but the used disc is right. Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1):

By default, Windows can't read ext2/3/4 file systems - unless you specifically went out of your way to format your drive in a different file system when you installed Ubuntu, your files are probably in one of those file systems.

You'll need to install software on Windows that can read those file systems.

This article suggests three tools that you can try, but I don't have any personal experience with them myself: http://www.howtogeek.com/112888/3-ways-to-access-your-linux-partitions-from-windows/

If you try to read them from another Linux machine, you should not have this problem.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a live CD, Mount the drive and recover your files that way

```
 cd mkdir /mnt/backup
 sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/backup
```

You may need to change sda1 to match your actual settings.

Now you can access the drive from /mnt/backup

If you have a decent size usb drive, I would setup img on usb with persistence so you can recover your files of the flash later when you get Ubuntu back up.

If you want to be able to use the drive with Windows, you need a ntfs partition.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your replies. I tried 2 of the "Howtogeek" options but having downloaded them neither could see the Ubuntu HDD either when on USB or mounted in the desk unit. After many tries I had to disconnect the XP HDD to get the Ubuntu 12.4 load as thr master and then select the files manually to copy to the USB key. 
There were many visits to the internet to find where bookmarks, emails & address book files were hidden to copy. Then reconnect the XP drive and copy/paste or import the files where they ought to be after many more explorations of the web to discover where they needed to be.
There were a few things that didn't transfer or got corrupted but that's computers but 98% arrived where they were supposed to be after 48hrs of following advise given, my thanks as a complete novice I would either be at a computer engineer pleading for help and checking the bank account or on pills. 
Lesson learnt BACK UP or PRINT important files and before taking anything apart copy files to another storage device!
Those younger than 50 probably could have done this in an afternoon, its a language thing in some cases, but those more creaky are fumbling around in the dark as the computer speak is totally alien and we're worried about breaking what we don't understand beyond repair. 
Again my thanks its running!

P.S If the answers the computer what was the question?